# when using latex lstlistoflistings how can i have sections and subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, templates, sections-paragraphs

currently one of my latex template file uses Listing Package
then

```
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\lstlistoflistings

[%- FOREACH item = items -%]

   [%- IF item.type == 'business' -%]
% [% item.path %]
\begin{figure}[H]

   \includegraphics[figure]

   \caption{[%- item.caption -%]}

\end{figure}
\clearpage

   [%- ELSIF item.type == 'IT' -%]
\lstinputlisting[caption=[%- item.caption -%]]
```

.......

currently displaying plain TOC

```
list of figures
1 
2
3
4
5
listings
1
2
3
4 .....
```

My Desired TOC Format

```
Ta
list of figure
1
    1.1
    1.2 
....
2
    2.1
    2.2
    2.3
.....
Listings
1
2
3
4
```

Can any one please advise me how to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This 'template' file is a complete mess. I think, you have to reformulate your question

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully, does adding `\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}` to the preamble do what you want?

Comment: ok I shall reformulate my question in a simple way, For example

My current table of contents looks like the following based on above template :(


1 IT
2 IT System Administrator
3 IT Infrasturcture Engineer
4 IT Analyst 

My desired output is ,  

Table Of Contents

1.IT
 1.1 IT System Administrator
 1.2 IT Infrasturcture Engineer
 1.3 IT Analyst 
 

I have to change my template to identify the subsections and also number them accordingly.
Its very important for me to complete it but I am still struggling...

Comment: @Latex: Your question is still unclear. Apparently you have either chapters (IT, IT System Administrator), which is something like `book.cls`  or `sections` which is `article` - like. What does this have to do with the `listings` package?

Comment: As Christian I struggle to understand what you mean.  `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`? What does the list of figures and list of listings have to do with the table of content? We really need more information, so please make a complete, compilable example that we can copy-paste into our editors and test directly. You don't need much content, just some chapter/section/subsection headings and the ToC. If the lists of figures/listings are important, add one or two of each of those as well. (You don't need images/code, just  `figure`/`lstlisting` environments with captions.)

Comment: Should *IT Sys Admin* and *IT Infra Eng* and *IT Analyst* be subdivisions of the higher *IT*?

Comment: Latex, please edit your question rather than giving details in the comments! Also, please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/).